# How to override maven-core-2.0.7-uber.jar?

Tags: maven-2

My problem is that I am trying to use a specific JTidy version with maven (v8.0 or something). Everything works fine during compile time, but at runtime maven overrides the JTidy in the pom.xml with its own implementation in `maven-core-2.0.7-uber.jar`.

See also [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716290/how-to-find-out-what-jar-file-provides-a-class-during-runtime-using-maven).

What can be done? My application compiles fine but fails at runtime because the classloader loads the file from `maven-core-2.0.7-uber.jar` instead of the one given in `pom.xml`. Is there some way to force it at runtime or preferably at compile time?

Comment: Ideally, you should open an issue in Maven's Jira (that would help the whole community as the solution is more a workaround than a real solution, there is a classloading bug somewhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the correct version in a `<dependencyManagement>` element should override the default.

A workaround is to replace the JTidy JAR in your local copy of the maven repository with the version you want.

I also suggest to try Maven 2.2. They changed the artifact lookup rules, that might fix your issue. And have a look at the effective POM (`mvn help:effective-pom`) to see which rules apply for plugin lookup.

Comment: I have the correct version in <pre>dependencyManagement</pre> but <pre>Maven completely ignores it</pre> because it has its own Tidy without any dependency management. I will try newer Maven, hope it does not break anything.

Comment: You mean the class files for JTidy are inside of maven-core-2.0.7-ueber.jar?