# Primefaces updated to 3.4.2 but still showing as Running on PrimeFaces 3.1.1

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf-2, primefaces

I was using Primefaces 3.1.1 and I today I have updated to 3.4.2 and to get the corresponding jar I have changed my in my pom.xml to the following and it has successfully downloaded 3.4.2 jar.

```
<!-- Primefaces library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Problem is when I start my server it is still showing as

```
Running on PrimeFaces 3.1.1
```

I did clean project, install maven, build project etc, but of no use.

How can I point to Primefaces 3.4.2?

I am using Eclipse Helios and Glassfish 3.

Thanks

Comment: try 2 search for `3.1.1` string in your project... ? maybe you left it somewhere.... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classpath might contain old primefaces jar. You could find out what jar provides the primefaces class. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716290/how-to-find-out-what-jar-file-provides-a-class-during-runtime-using-maven) and try to locate your primeface jar and remove it from classpath.

Comment: Your answer led me to do something else as you suggested this could be a class path problem. What I did is I renamed 3.1.1 folder to something else and then did a project clean. Doing this has forced to switch to 3.4.2. Thanks a for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to check web server class path, i have encountered with the same problem. I solved it by removed the old version on my Tomcat class path.