# About Adding import package in Groovy by customizing compilation process

Tags: java, grails, groovy, junit

I am writing a java file in which i am parsing the given groovy file using GroovyClassLoader to find the class in it. To do this, i have to import some class (like org.junit.Test) and add  package and add static import also. Since i am using old groovy version 1.6, i can not use compilation customizers as these classes not available in this version. So to import custom classes, i had to write custom groovy class loader by extending groovy class loader class like below,

...

```
public static class DefaultImportClassLoader extends GroovyClassLoader {
public DefaultImportClassLoader(ClassLoader cl){
    super(cl);
}

public CompilationUnit createCompilationUnit(CompilerConfiguration config, CodeSource codeSource) {
         CompilationUnit cu = super.createCompilationUnit(config, codeSource);
         cu.addPhaseOperation(new SourceUnitOperation() {
         public void call(SourceUnit source) throws CompilationFailedException {
             //source.getAST().addImport("Test",ClassHelper.make("org.junit.Test")); //working
        source.getAST().addImportPackage("org.junit.");
        }}, Phases.CONVERSION);

        return cu;
    }
```

}

here add import package is not working. Would any one give right suggestion way of using addImportPackage().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your code and works perfectly for me. (with groovy-all-1.6.9.jar) (edit: groovy-all-1.6.0.jar works fine too)
How do you use your class `DefaultImportClassLoader`?
I've done:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
        GroovyClassLoader loader = new DefaultImportClassLoader(new GroovyClassLoader());
        Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(DefaultImportClassLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("so_22729226/test.groovy"));
        GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
        groovyObject.invokeMethod("run", null);
    }
```

With this Groovy class:

```
class so_22729226_Test {
    def run(){
        print Test.class
    }
}
```

And I get the expected output: `interface org.junit.Test`

If I use the standard loader I get:

```
 Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Test for class: so_22729226_Test
```

Which is the expected behaviour too.

Comment: Thank you fonkap for the reply.

Comment: I am running like as below to know class name inside some groovy file.

Comment: GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyScriptTestRun.DefaultImportClassLoader(
GroovyScriptTestRun.class.getClassLoader());
scriptClass = classLoader.parseClass(filePath);
System.out.println("Script Class Name ->"+scriptClass.getSimpleName());

Comment: Could you try: `GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyScriptTestRunInstance.DefaultImportClassLoader(new GroovyClassLoader());` instead? Could you also try my test groovy class (`so_22729226_Test`) to see if it works?

Comment: I tried with your script as well. Its working when i try to import only Test class and printed class name. But same is not working when i try to import package. it means parseClass() is failing somewhere but not throwing any exception also

Comment: I can't figure which is the difference between our code. Please try my complete example. [Here](http://pastebin.com/BUV9gdga) . I'm using groovy-all-1.6.0.jar

Comment: Thanks for your support. I tested your program it's working with package. I tested in my env.  It is not working in my env when i run my environment with ant setup, i somehow now managed to print the exception as below

Comment: [exec] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ModuleNode.addImportPackage(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: This looks like there are 2 different jars i am working with. May be in IDE, i am pointing one version and in ant env it may be pointing another version which did not have this method. I have to debug this. Any comments much appreciated. Thanks for your support

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to deal with class loading problems, especially in JEE apps. Id suggest trying this sentence to check from which jar the class is. `System.out.println(org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ModuleNode.class.getResource("ModuleNode.class"));`. Good luck!

Comment: Atlast i found the root cause that i am using groovy 1.6.4 version during development but groovy 2.1.6 is used during runtime which doesn't have addimportpackage unfortunately. Your idea helped me to think me to find the right jar at runtime. Thank you very much. by refering this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716290/how-to-find-out-what-jar-file-provides-a-class-during-runtime-using-maven